# Is it ok to use axios.delete - axios.post and get in same page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am new in React/Node world, so i just wanted to ask, is it ok to use like 2-3 times axios in the same page. For example to use axios.get, axios.post and axios.get one more time? I wanted to creat new project and just checking  ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can have any number of ajax calls from a single page depending on your use cases. Especially where React is often used to build SPAs (single-page apps), you don't have page loads between route changes, but you can perform many actions/calls to your server all on the same page.